# Sound works, but testing speakers does not work anymore. Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gnome, sound

Ubuntu 20.04.3

Generally sound workes in my system. In web browsers, system etc. But not (only) in "testing speakers" option in Gnome Settings.
It (testing sound) worked till yesterday but today stoped.

What whould be the cause?

My system:
Laptop Dell Latitude 5511

```
$ uname -srv
Linux 5.13.0-28-generic #31~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 19 14:08:10 UTC 2022

$ sudo lspci -vv | grep -i audio
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH cAVS (prog-if 80)

$ sudo lshw -C multimedia
  *-usb:3                   
       description: Video
       product: Integrated_Webcam_HD
       vendor: CN0V976R8LG000CPB2XRA01
       physical id: b
       bus info: usb@1:b
       version: 82.56
       serial: 200901010001
       capabilities: usb-2.01
       configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
  *-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       product: Comet Lake PCH cAVS
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
   resources: irq:178 memory:cc338000-cc33bfff memory:cc000000-cc0fffff

$ pactl info
Server String: /run/user/1000/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 33
Server Protocol Version: 33
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 45
Tile Size: 65472
User Name: krzysiek
Host Name: myhost
Server Name: pulseaudio
Server Version: 13.99.1
Default Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.hdmi-stereo-extra2
Default Source: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
Cookie: 35e8:aae4

$ pactl list short
0   module-device-restore       
1   module-stream-restore       
2   module-card-restore     
3   module-augment-properties       
4   module-switch-on-port-available     
5   module-switch-on-connect        
6   module-udev-detect      
7   module-alsa-card    device_id="0" name="pci-0000_00_1f.3" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1"    
8   module-bluetooth-policy     
9   module-bluetooth-discover       
10  module-bluez5-discover      
11  module-native-protocol-unix     
12  module-default-device-restore       
13  module-always-sink      
14  module-intended-roles       
15  module-suspend-on-idle      
16  module-console-kit      
17  module-systemd-login        
18  module-position-event-sounds        
19  module-role-cork        
20  module-snap-policy      
21  module-filter-heuristics        
22  module-filter-apply     
23  module-x11-publish  display=:0 xauthority=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority 
24  module-x11-cork-request display=:0 xauthority=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority 
25  module-x11-xsmp display=:0 xauthority=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority session_manager=local/aps00090646-mb.poland.asseco.corp:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/4554,unix/aps00090646-mb.poland.asseco.corp:/tmp/.ICE-unix/4554 
2   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.hdmi-stereo-extra2 module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
1   alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo   module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   RUNNING
3   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.hdmi-stereo-extra2.monitor module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
1   1   10  protocol-native.c   float32le 1ch 25Hz
0   module-systemd-login.c  (null)
4   module-x11-xsmp.c   (null)
5   protocol-native.c   gnome-shell
6   protocol-native.c   gsd-media-keys
10  protocol-native.c   gnome-control-center
41  protocol-native.c   msedge
46  protocol-native.c   pactl
0   alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3  module-alsa-card.c
```

[image: does not worked in this place only]

Comment: Have you rebooted yet? Also, what choices do you see in the Output Device popup in the Sound settings panel?

Comment: @heynnema I see properly my speakers, and when i connect my HDMI display: this hdmi device. All looks visualy good. Yes, I rebooted several times

Comment: Boot to an older kernel from the GRUB menu and see if it starts working. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema booted previous kernel [5.13.0-27-generic] doesnt chenged behaviour od speakers test. :(

Comment: @heynnema I found resolution! Rejoice! :D

Comment: Good job! Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 7):

When I put in Terminal:

```
gnome-control-center
```

and next: sound --> test speakers,
in my Terminal I get output:

```
(gnome-control-center:9338): sound-cc-panel-WARNING **: 15:57:30.442: Failed to play sound: No such driver
```

Next i pasted this to google search and found resolution on webpage https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1879989/comments/5
The problem was caused by missed libcanberra-pulse.

```
sudo apt install libcanberra-pulse
```

Problem resolved.
Test speakers worked now:)